# RandomORG API in NodeJS returning undefined values

Tags: javascript, node.js, random

As the title says, I'm trying to use the RandomORG API to generate (true)random numbers, the only thing whenever I try to generate a random number in my NodeJS it returns undefined.

This is how I do it:

```
    var RandomOrgAPI = require('random');
    var die;

    //Here I log a random integer to the console.
    console.log("" + RandomOrgAPI.integer({min:1,max:5,num:1},function(result){console.log(die = result[0])}));
```

Comment: Please show actual command line error.

Comment: `RandomOrgAPI.integer` is an asynchronous method, it won't return the result, it'll call the `callback` parameter with the result as it's first parameter. `console.log` can't possibly show anything but the result of `"" + undefined`.

Comment: Does the `console.log` *inside* the callback ever run or not?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely failing to load the library correctly.

Try this

```
var RandomOrgAPI = require('random-org-api');
```

and don't forget to install the library like so:

```
npm install random-org-api
```

From their docs it looks like it should be `.integers` not `.integer`

```
var die;
RandomOrgAPI.integers({min:1,max:6,num:1},function(result){console.log(die = result[0])});
```

Comment: I checked their github and they said I had to do npm install random. I'll try it out tho!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-org-api is what i was looking at.  I would use a differnet package.  That one is very old.  Try this:https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-js

Comment: TypeError: RandomOrgAPI.integer is not a function
    at toWin (/home/bot/site.js:1762:35)
    at null._repeat (/home/bot/site.js:1724:5)
    at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:275:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

Comment: Is the npmjs.com/package/random-js package true randomness?

Comment: Yes, it is based on <random> from c++.

Comment: Also. The docs show a `.integers`  api call but not a `.integer`

Comment: Okay, this works but can it generate a true random number like Math.random() between 0 and 1?

Comment: Or would I have to generate a number between 0 and 100000000000000000 and divide that by 100000000000000000 to get a double between 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes. You should read their docs.  They talk about RNG distribution problems and how they address them.

Comment: well I can't really seem to find anything that has to do with numbers going from 0 to 1.00000000000000000

Comment: `r.real(min, max, inclusive): Produce a floating point number within the range [min, max) or [min, max]. Uses 53 bits of randomness.`

Comment: Well, I know Math.random uses a decimal between 0 and 1.00000000000000000, so could I do r.real(0, 1.00000000000000000)?

Comment: `0` is an integer so `0.0` is better for at least being more readable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check whether you are using correct package or not
You are using `random` package but the code seems to be related with `random.js` as you are using `.integer()`

If not then the do `npm i random --save`, the below code works fine use the `generateIntegers()` function call

source code exposes `generateIntegers(callback,options,errorCallback)`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/random with the github code link

https://github.com/rcombs/node-random/blob/master/main.js

```
const RandomOrgAPI = require("random");
var die;
options = {
    secure: true, // Make the request secure
    num: 1,      // Get 1 integer
    min: 1,     // Minimum of 1
    max: 5,      // Maximum of 5
}
function randomCallback(integers){
    die = integers[0][0];
    console.log(integers[0][0]) // will print a random number between 1 and 5
}
RandomOrgAPI.generateIntegers(randomCallback,options);
```